# How do I make a USB stick that will install both windows xp and linux?

Tags: windows, linux, usb, installation

I would like to have the option to install winxp or ubuntu from the same 4gb drive. Is there any easy way to do this? I looked around on google and I saw a textwall or two.

Answer (score 2):

Try [MultiBootUSB](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-multiboot-usb/).

> How to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive that you can use to Boot Multiple ISO Files from USB. [sic]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make two partitions, and then use unetbootin to install

Answer (score 0):

[YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) has support for multiple OS's.  I know that Windows Vista and 7 work well, however I do not know if it works with Windows XP.  Either way I would start there.